# Doesn't work Keys.CONTROL in WebDriver

Tags: webdriver

help me please, i have a WebDriver script:

```
package AdvancedInteraction;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class ActionClick {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("file:///C:/Selectable.html");
        WebElement one = driver.findElement(By.name("one"));
        WebElement three = driver.findElement(By.name("three"));
        WebElement five = driver.findElement(By.name("five"));
        // Add all the actions into the Actions builder.
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
        .click(one)
        .click(three)
        .click(five)
        .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
        // Generate the composite action.
        Action compositeAction = builder.build();
        // Perform the composite action.
        compositeAction.perform();
    }
}
```

but when i execute this script it doesn't click with CONTROL button. Why does it happen ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this may be a bug with selenium - see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3734.

There are some workarounds in that thread, but I would suggest to perhaps instead of building an action chain like this, specify the click method with a keydown modifier. So you can

```
Actions click1 = new Actions(driver);
click1.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
click1.click(one);
click.perform();
```

perhaps that may get around some of the issues you've been seeting.